# Initial component screen won't route after upgrading react-navigation from 4.x to 5.1

Tags: react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-bottom-tab

The `react-navigation` is upgraded from 4.x to 5.x on my React Native 0.61 app. There are quite a lot of changes which may break in upgrade. My problem is that after upgrade, the initial screen stays and does not route even after clicking the component link on it.

Here is part of the dependencies in `package.json` for `react-navigation`:

```
"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.2.2",
"@react-navigation/native": "^5.1.0",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^5.2.1",
```

Here is my `App.js` (sorry it is a little messy. Also reduce the 3 tabs to one initial screen only).  The first component loaded is a SplashScrren which retrieves data from the local drive. After that, `App` is loaded. `App` has one bottom tab `Event`. When clicking an event on the list, a `Chat` is loaded allowing user to chat with other users.

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';
import GLOBAL from "./src/lib/global";
import SplashScreen from "./src/components/splashscreen/SplashScreen";
import globalContext from "./src/components/splashscreen/GlobalContext";
import { enableScreens } from 'react-native-screens';

enableScreens();

//import helper from "./src/lib/helper";

const instructions = Platform.select({
  ios: 'Press Cmd+R to reload,\n' + 'Cmd+D or shake for dev menu',
  android:
    'Double tap R on your keyboard to reload,\n' +
    'Shake or press menu button for dev menu',
});

//socket.io
const socket = io(GLOBAL.BASE_URL, {
    transports: ['websocket'],
    jsonp: false
  });
console.log("socket id in App.js : ", socket.id);

socket.on('disconnect', (reason) => {
  // ...
  if (reason === 'io server disconnect') {
    // the disconnection was initiated by the server, you need to reconnect manually
    socket.connect();
  }

});

const BTab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const EventStack = (data) => {
  console.log("data in eventStack : ", data);
  const EventWithSelf = (props) => (<Event {...props} myself={data.data.myself} grp_name={data.data.grp_name} token={data.data.result} group_id={data.data.group_id} alias={data.data.alias} grpmember_id={data.data.grpmember_id} role={data.data.role} device_id={data.data.device_id} />)
  const NewEventWithSelf = (props) => (<NewEvent {...props} myself={data.myself} token={data.result} role={data.role} group_id={data.group_id} grpmember_id={data.data.grpmember_id} device_id={data.data.device_id} />)
  const EditEventWithSelf = (props) => (<EditEvent {...props} myself={data.data.myself} token={data.data.result} device_id={data.data.device_id} role={data.data.role} />)
  const ChatWithSocket = (props) => (<Chat {...props} socket={socket} myself={data.data.myself} token={data.data.result} alias={data.data.alias} grpmember_id={data.data.grpmember_id} role={data.data.role} group_id={data.data.group_id} device_id={data.data.device_id}/>);
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen 
        name="Event" 
        component={EventWithSelf} 
      />
      <Stack.Screen 
        name="New Event" 
        component={NewEventWithSelf} 
      />
      <Stack.Screen 
        name="Edit Event" 
        component={EditEventWithSelf} 
      />
      <Stack.Screen 
        name="Chat" 
        component={ChatWithSocket} 
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};    

function AppScreen ({route, navigation}) {

  const authContext = React.createContext(null);
  const stateContext = React.createContext(null);
  const propsContext = React.createContext(null);
  console.log("route in AppScreen : ", route);
  const {data} = route.params;
  console.log("data in AppScreen : ", data);
  const [myself, setMyself] = useState(data.myself);
  const [result, setResult] = useState(data.result);
  const [group_id, setGroup_id] = useState(data.group_id);
  const [grpmember_id, setGrpmember_id] = useState(data.grpmember_id);
  const [role, setRole] = useState(data.role);
  const [alias, setAlias] = useState(data.alias);
  const [contact_id, setContact_id] = useState(data.contact_id);
  const [grp_name, setGrp_name] = useState(data.grp_name);
  const [device_id, setDevice_id] = useState(data.device_id);
  const [success, setSuccess] = useState(data.success);
  //
  const SignupWithDeviceId = (props) => (<Signup {...props} device_id={device_id} />);
  const Verif1WithDeviceId = (props) => (<Verif1 {...props} device_id={device_id} />);

  var data1 = {
    myself,
    result,
    group_id,
    grpmember_id,
    grp_name,
    role,
    alias,
    contact_id,
    device_id,
    success,
  };

  const Eventstack = (props) => (<EventStack {...props} data={data1}/>);
  const Groupstack = (props) => (<GroupStack {...props} data={data1}/>);
  const Contactstack = (props) => (<ContactStack {...props} data={data1}/>);

  updateGroup = (group_id1, grp_name1) => {
    setGroup_id(group_id1);
    setGrp_name(grp_name1);
  };

  updateToken = (result1) => {
    setResult(result1);
  };

  updateGrpmember = (grpmember_id1, alias1, role1, contact_id1) => {
    setGrpmember_id(grpmember_id1);
    setAlias(alias1);
    setRole(role1);
    setContact_id(contact_id1);
  };

  if (!data1.success || !result || !myself) {
    return (     
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Signup">
        <Stack.Screen name="Signup" component={SignupWithDeviceId} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Verif1" component={Verif1WithDeviceId} />
        <Stack.Screen name="SplashScreen" component={SplashScreen} options={{headerShown:false}}/>
      </Stack.Navigator>
    )
  };
  let authVal = {
    myself,
    result,  
    updateToken,  
  }
  let stateVal = {
    group_id,
    grp_name,
    role,
    alias,
    updateGroup,
    updateGrpmember,
  }
  let propsVal = {
    device_id,
  }
  return (
    <propsContext.Provider value={propsVal}>
      <authContext.Provider value={authVal}>
        <stateContext.Provider value={stateVal}>
        <BTab.Navigator>
            <BTab.Screen name="Event" component={Eventstack} />

        </BTab.Navigator>
        </stateContext.Provider>
      </authContext.Provider>
    </propsContext.Provider>

  );
};

export default function App() {

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator InitialRouteName="Splash">
        <Stack.Screen name="Splash" component={SplashScreen} options={{headerShown:false}}/>
        <Stack.Screen name="App" component={AppScreen} options={{headerShown:false}} />
      </Stack.Navigator>

    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Here is the `Event` component loaded initially.

[image]

When clicking `test`, the `Chat` component shall be loaded but it didn't and the screen remains unchanged. Even though the log file did show that the code of `Chat` component was executed. What is wrong with my `react-navigation` upgrade?